# jquery selector for php-generated class

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

In wordpress, I created a div within the post preview, something like

```
<div class="postbox">  
<h2><a class="showhide" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>  
<div class="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"></div>
</div>
```

now, I want to make a jquery selector for that inner div.

I have defined

```
var post_url = $(this).attr("href");
var post_id = $(this).attr("rel");
```

to accomplish something like

```
 $(".post-"[post_id]).html("loading...");
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Javascript string concatenation is off. Please try:

```
$(".post-" + post_url).html("loading...");
```